# open a url inside of div using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str,st1)
{
if (str=="" AND st1=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.tndte.com/Result/Default2.aspx?Value="+str"regul="+st,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form>
Enter the Register No: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="reg"/><br /><br />
<input type="radio" value="K"  name="s1" >K/L/R/O/N-scheme &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="J" name="s1" >J/C/D/G-scheme
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="View" name="submit" id="valuebtn" onClick="oload()" /> 
</form>
</center>

<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function oload(){
    document.getElementById('valuebtn').onclick = function() {
    var s = document.getElementById('reg').value;
    var ss = document.getElementById('s1').value;
    showUser(s,ss);
    }
}   
</script>
</html>
```

The above program is written for checking result myself with the help of original website. with the help of ajax XMLHttpRequest, am passing the values over function. but it not response. can any one help me.?

Comment: Why write your own AJAX handler when you're already using jQuery?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving. Is it hitting the server?

Comment: One possible error is you're missing "&" between the parameters in query string... http://www.tndte.com/Result/Default2.aspx?Value="+str"&regul="+st

Comment: No, you're not using JQuery..check out JQuery's GET operation and get rid of xmlhttprequest .. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Are you able to open the debug window? Menu->Tools->Javascript console in Chrome. Should tell you the error there.

Comment: but when i click the button the address bar load the following the url only.. "http://localhost/ex4.html?reg=12119291&s1=K&submit=View" is it correct??

Comment: Use tools such as fiddler, Firefox firebug to check the status of async operations and you'll know how to proceed further.

Comment: Please check answers provided, answer is already present. Try to spend time by taking leads and post questions if you're not able to succeed after several attempts.

Comment: You are missing a `+` after `+str`.

Comment: ya thanks, now pgm has error free. but no output. i mentioned past comment the addrss bar load the local url only. is it correct?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

Are they from the same origin? If not:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests

and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

`AND` is not a javascript keyword. Use `&&` in your `if` statement.